# AngularJS controller testing scope undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, browserify

I'm having an issue testing an AngularJS controller. The controller uses a 
service to fetch some data and put it on the $scope.

```
// src/controllers/posts.js
module.exports = ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {
  posts.refresh(function(err, data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  });
}]

// src/services/posts.js
module.exports = ['$http', function($http) {
  this.refresh = function(callback) {
    $http.get('/posts')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(null, data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      });
  };
}]

// src/app.js
var angular = require('angular');
var PostsController = require('./controllers/posts');
var PostsService = require('./services/posts');

var simpleApp = angular.module('simple-app', []);

simpleApp.controller('PostsController', PostsController);

simpleApp.service('posts', PostsService);
```

This all works when I run it in the browser. I have a functioning test for the service that works with Karma and Jasmine. The problem I'm having with the controller test is that the result is that $scope is undefined.

Here is the test:

```
// test/controllers/posts.test.js
var fixtures = require('../fixtures/posts');

describe('PostsController', function() {
  var PostsController, scope;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('simple-app'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _posts_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    PostsController = function() {
      return $controller('PostsController', {
        $scope: scope,
        posts: _posts_
      });
    };
  }));

  it('should set the posts on the scope', function() {
    debugger; // shows me that the scope's posts property isn't set
    var controller = PostsController();
    expect(scope.posts).toEqual(fixtures);
  });
});
```

From the documentation, $controller returns a new instance of the specified controller. So when I'm calling `PostsController()` it should return the new instance with the dependencies injected right? When the instance is instantiated it should run the controller function, manipulating the scope that was injected in the test. Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:** I've added $httpBackend to the test but now the test says httpBackend is undefined. Here's the code (only the functions that changed):

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(
  function($rootScope, $controller, _posts_, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    PostsController = function() {
      return $controller('PostsController', {
        $scope: scope,
        posts: _posts_
      });

    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  };
}));

it('should set the posts on the scope', function() {
  debugger; // checking httpBackend here says httpBackend is undefined
  httpBackend.whenGET('/posts').respond(fixtures);

  var controller = PostsController();
  expect(scope.posts).toEqual(fixtures);
});
```

Comment: I'd be wary of `PostController()` here. The second point about the first argument to [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller) (i.e. _check if evaluating the string on the **current scope** returns a constructor_ - emphasis mine) could be why you're seeing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Is scope undefined or is scope.posts undefined? If scope.post is undefined you probably need to set up a $httpBackend for the url /posts and return a value as well as call scope.digest to get the promise resolved. About the PostController function I don't see any problems. Used the same pattern in my tests without any trouble.